# Manipulate slugs and urls on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Is there an away to create "virtual" slugs on wordpress?

For example:
I create a custom post type named "year" and the slug is /year/. This custom post type was only created to generate the slugs(/year/). I don't have any post inside this custom post type.

I want to type url /year/1988/ and the Wordpress call the single.php file.
If I do it today the wordpress will return 404 because 1988 needs to be a post inside the custom post type(year).

I need some .php code or .htaccess to do something like: If type something after /year/ its load the single file because I can't create a conditional for each year, 1901, 1902, 1903 ... and I will take this information and make the necessary query.

Comment: "I want to type url /year/1988/ and the Wordpress call the single.php file." > The single.php to display what exactly?

Comment: It's not really clear what is it you're trying to do. Please explain in more detail, otherwise we can't help you out.

Comment: @Michael the single.php file is the template to show post content. 
I don't have any post inside /year/ like (1988, 1987...)  but I have year information inside other post. 
on single.php I have a sql query that return post and use some information like year to filter it.

I'd like to access the /year/1988/ and hit the single.php file not 404 to filter all posts with 1988 on post field

Comment: I just feel that you are not using Wordpress the way it's meant to be used. Custom SQL queries on single.php, creating CPT only for the slug - maybe it would be better if you wrote your own logic? Have you tried adding a custom [rewrite endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint). Your endpoint would be `year` and the query var would be ie. `1988`. You can get the query var using `get_query_var`. Then do a template redirect on your `single.php`.

Comment: @Michael sorry about that but I'm using wordpress with acf. 
I only using the SQL query instead of wp-query is because I have about 10 custom field inside post(and each field is a cpt) and wp-query make a lot of requests/query to list only one information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need this to work on your home page **only** (ie. `mysite.org/years/1988`) you can add a custom rewrite tag and rule:

```
add_filter( 'init', function() {

     add_rewrite_tag( '%years%', '([^&]+)' );

     // Match the front page and pass years value as a query var.
     add_rewrite_rule( '^years/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?years=$matches[1]', 'top' );

});
```

Then use the new query var to load a different template:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) {

 if ( get_query_var( 'years' ) ) {

   $new_template = locate_template( array( 'single.php' ) );
   if ( !empty( $new_template ) ) {
       return $new_template;
   }
 }
 return $template;

});
```

I tried to use `year`, but it wouldn't work, I think it's a reserved query var used by Wordpress. And don't forget to flush your toilet, I mean rewrite rules ;).

Comment: Sorry, the name is years because year is reserved.
The code not work. The others cpt that was working stopped and show this message Stylesheet is missing.

If I try to access the /years/1988 it's return 404

Comment: I updated my answer. This is now **only** going to work on your front/home page.

Comment: Yes I flushed.
The entire website back to works but /year/number return 404

Comment: I ran this code on my local machine and it works. If you still get a 404 on your `homepage/years/1988`, then there's another issue with your code/installation.

Comment: Did you flush the rewrite only saving or in functions.php?

This is my htacess to you check if it's necessary to add something;
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project-x/www/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Sorry about that but the cpt Years was enable and it make the code not work.
It's works.